# LuaJ: Combine multiple byte code chunks into single chunk

Tags: lua, luaj

I have couple of pre-compiled lua-scripts, I would like to combine them and dump into single byte-code chunk. The pre-compiled scripts can be dependent on each other.

In C, I could do this using:

`luaL_loadfile` / `luaL_loadfile` / `lua_dump`

But I am not sure how to do this using LuaJ. 
I am using luaj-3.0-alpha2 release.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `os.execute('luac ...')` :-)